# Can derived classes have static get methods?

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

**Update 2, added Gist**:

Question: **Can derived classes have `static get` methods?**
[3 files here](https://gist.github.com/sdtsui/760cc758744d09e52097), with attempted use of `static get` method in a derived class. It works correctly when accessed inside the class' `.es6` file, but doesn't when imported for tests.

---

I'm just getting my head around ES6 class syntax, but am strong/comfortable in ES5 prototypal inheritance. I'm working on a set of tree data structures. Using Babel.

I have a derived class, RBTree:
(see code below)

I want RBTree to have a `static get` method, that simply serves as a pointer/property to a null node I have already created. Say I have imported that node from another file, and it is called `NULL_POINTER`.

How do I get this static get method to return `NULL_POINTER`?

When I import it and try to access like so above, `.null` returns `undefined`.

I also have tried modifying RBTree outside of the class expression (`RBTree.nullPointer =` //...), which does not work.

---

**Update 1**:
Renamed some things. Code updated to reflect naming.
I have a working implementation of my original test spike. Here are the relevant files:

`RBTree.es6`

```
import {NULL_POINTER} from 'file/with/null/pointer'
export const _NULL_SENTINEL = new RBNode()// constructs the null node
export class RBTree extends BST {
  constructor() {

//...super call
  }

//...
  static get _nil() {
    return _NULL_SENTINEL;
  }
}
```

In my Jest testfile:

```
const RBTree = require('../../../src/binary_trees/RBTree');
const RBNode = require('../../../src/binary_trees/RBNode');
```

When I step through the tests with with node-inspector:
1. At the bottom of RBTree.es6, RBTree._nil works correctly.
2. If I place a debugger after the lines in the testfile, RBTree._nil returns `undefined`.
3. RBTree._NULL_SENTINEL is the same object.

1 and 3 are working as expected.
Is the reason behind 2, that RBTree's `static get` function is running in a different scope and no longer has access to `_NULL_SENTINEL`? (due two separate `export`s?)

I'd want to attach something to the RBTree object such that the `static get` will work, but I'd prefer it not to be a pointer on `this`.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access it and are you sure `NULL_POINTER` is not `undefined`? Since the syntax is correct, either `NULL_POINTER` doesn't have the value you think it does or you are not accessing it correctly, or your transpiler (if you use one) makes a mistake.

Comment: I'm now exporting both the pointer and RBTree separately, and I can access them, but I still can't get the `static get _nil()` function to work. When I step through in my test file, the function itself is `undefined`, and I can't step inside it. That's what has me confused.

Comment: Dropped the files into a fiddle, separating the 3 files with comments. The failing test / example of my problem at the bottom.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danielt213/L0uz1a4o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not importing the classes correctly. Since you are using a *named* export, you have to use a *named* import. As you can see through `RBTree._NULL_SENTINEL`, all the exports become properties of module. (why would `_NULL_SENTINEL` be a static property of the class `RBTree`? You are never assigning it to `RBTree`)

---

With ES6 it would be

```
import {RBTree} from '../../../src/binary_trees/RBTree';
```

and with CommonJS:

```
const RBTree = require('../../../src/binary_trees/RBTree').RBTree;
```

Comment: How would you create the intended null node in RBTree.es6 and assign it to RBTree?

Comment: Say the null node is assigned to `const _NULL_SENTINEL` one line above the RBTree class definition.   1. would `static get null() {return _NULL_SENTINEL}` work? 2. would `RBTree.null = _NULL_SENTINEL` one line underneath the declared class (for example, on the last line of the file) also work?

Comment: They don't seem to be working (named import, static get method), but I think this question has been answered completely, as it is related to module importing.  Thanks. I'll add to comments if I get another gist up.